# Artifactory github Repository - downloadBranch

Tags: github, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I have github setup as a VCS repository in Artifactory. When using the `downloadBrach` API through Artifactory (similar to downloading files via `git clone`), the download appears to include everything *except* the dot hidden files (.gitignore is an example).

Is there a way to include *all* files (including the dot hidden files) when downloading a branch from an Artifactory VCS repository?

This is what I've tried:

```
curl -XGET "https://artifactory.domainname.com/artifactory/api/vcs/downloadBranch/github-remote-vcs/jquery/jquery/master" -o jqueryMaster.tar.gz
```

This results in a gzipped tarball that contains all files in the repo, except for the dot hidden files but I need all files in the repo.

## Update #1

Slight correction - the dot hidden files *are* getting downloaded with the exception of the .git subdirectory containing information about the Repo itself.  Does anyone know if there is a way to get the .git directory as well as the Repo metadata included?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know if there is a way to get the .git directory as well as the Repo metadata included?

No: [The downloadBranch](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/VCS+Repositories#VCSRepositories-DownloadBranch) is for  downloading a tarball (tar.gz/zip, default tar.gz) of a complete branch.

It is an archive, not a full repo history.

[Exposing a VCS history through Artifactory API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/VCS+Repositories#VCSRepositories-UsingtheAPI) is for downloading archives only, not a full repo.

> - List all tags
> - List all branches
> - Download a specific tag
> - Download a file within a tag
> - Download a specific branch
> - Download a file within a branch
> - Download a release

Comment: This is exactly what I suspected, but appreciate the confirmation.